# Android: Rotate bitmap once or use EXIF orientation to rotate imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, rotation, exif

I am building an app that relies on showing quite a few bitmap images taken from the camera. I want all of the images to show with a 90 degree (portrait) orientation, and I know how I can do this with the EXIF information provided with each image. Would it be a better idea for me to rotate the bitmap of an image to fit my needs right after it is taken and then send it to my server, or should I send the image to my server without rotating it and then whenever I pull it down, use the EXIF rotation provided with the image to rotate the image view I am displaying it in? I need a solution that is memory efficient and fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since bitmap is just a matrix with the some data in every cell it should have the same weight (in terms of mb) if it's portrait or landscape, in case you need the images to be in a 90 deg. tilt ALL the time I would probabley do it before sending it to the server since (by my logic) you would probabley pull it ALOT more than upload it (which will only happen once..) so saving it on the way you are going to display it will basically have no effect on it's weight consumption HOWEVER since you are going to display it alot (again, by my logic since you keep it in a server) saving it alreay rotated will probabley save some other clients the hassle from doing that themselves..

Comment: Thanks, I will rotate it before sending it to the server and see how that works.